# Output array to multiple inputs

Tags: jquery

```
getDate: function(formated) {
                if (this.size() > 0) {
                    return prepareDate($('#' + $(this).data('datepickerId')).data('datepicker'))[formated ? 0 : 1];
                }
            }
```

In this part I'm creating the array

now with this part I'm getting the array to the input

```
onChange: function(formated, dates){
    $('#outDate').val(formated);
}
```

output is somthing like this:

> 09 May 2014,24 May 2014

now I'm willing to get

the first of the array to `<input class="inputDate" id="checkin" />`
and the next one to `<input class="inputDate" id="outDate" />`

so the output needs to be

09 May 2014 in the *checkin* and 24 May 2014 in the *checkout*

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var formated = "09 May 2014,24 May 2014";
var checkInDate = formated.split(',')[0];
var checkOutDate = formated.split(',')[1];
```

This should give you two dates in separate vars from a string.

```
var formated = ["09 May 2014","24 May 2014"];
var checkInDate = formated[0];
var checkOutDate = formated[1];
```

This should give you two dates in separate vars from a string array.

Use them. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.html:25
$.DatePicker.onChange index.html:25
click datepicker.js:571
jQuery.event.handle jquery.js:2693
(anonymous function)

Comment: Check what is null. You must be trying to operate on a string or array which is null. @IvoJonkers

Comment: When i'm trying to split it is saying it's null

Comment: @IvoJonkers Is `formated` a String or String array? And make sure its not null.

Comment: This is the working answer  var checkdates = formated.toString().split(','); so was missing the .toString

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just taking right index element of the array:

```
onChange: function(formated, dates){
   var values = formated.split(',');
   $('#checkin').val(values[0]); // takes first date
   $('#outDate').val(values[1]); // takes second date
}
```